# What is the best way to listen for component resize events within an Angular2 component?

Tags: angular

I'm writing an Angular2 component that needs to dynamically change its content when resized. I am using the experimental Renderer in @angular/core (v2.1.0) and can wire up a click listener with the following:

```
this.rollupListener = this.renderer.listen(this.rollUp, 'click', (event) => {
  ...
});
```

But unfortunately I cannot do the same for a resize event - both 'resize' or 'onresize' do not work:

```
this.resizeListener = this.renderer.listen(this.container, 'resize', (event) => {
  // this never fires :(
});
```

I am able to pick up on browser resize events using the following:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event.target'])
onResize() {
  ...
}
```

But unfortunately not all component resizing in my application is due to a browser resize.

Basically, I'm looking for the JQuery equivalent of:

```
$(this.container).resize(() => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thete is no resize event on elements, only on window. jQuery probably uses polling.

Comment: Thanks for steering me in the right direction, Günter! I'll either make use of Marc's library http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/ or implement a directive that registers a mutation observer for an element.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up implementing a service that uses the element-resize-detector library (https://github.com/wnr/element-resize-detector). Couldn't find a TypeScript definition file but with a little help ([Use element-resize-detector library in an Angular2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027750/use-element-resize-detector-library-in-an-angular2-application/41043364#41043364)), implemented the following:

**element-resize-detector.d.ts**

```
declare function elementResizeDetectorMaker(options?: elementResizeDetectorMaker.ErdmOptions): elementResizeDetectorMaker.Erd;

declare namespace elementResizeDetectorMaker {
    interface ErdmOptions {
        strategy?: 'scroll' | 'object';
    }

    interface Erd {
        listenTo(element: HTMLElement, callback: (elem: HTMLElement) => void);
        removeListener(element: HTMLElement, callback: (elem: HTMLElement) => void);
        removeAllListeners(element: HTMLElement);
        uninstall(element: HTMLElement);
    }
}

export = elementResizeDetectorMaker;
```

**resize.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as elementResizeDetectorMaker from 'element-resize-detector';

@Injectable()
export class ResizeService {
  private resizeDetector: any;

  constructor() {
    this.resizeDetector = elementResizeDetectorMaker({ strategy: 'scroll' });
  }

  addResizeEventListener(element: HTMLElement, handler: Function) {
    this.resizeDetector.listenTo(element, handler);
  }

  removeResizeEventListener(element: HTMLElement) {
    this.resizeDetector.uninstall(element);
  }
}
```

**my-component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ResizeService } from '../resize/index';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: ``
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private resizeService: ResizeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resizeService.addResizeEventListener(this.el.nativeElement, (elem) => {
      // some resize event code...
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.resizeService.removeResizeEventListener(this.el.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution for listening component resize events !

Comment: I couldn't get this to work using ang10 and gave up.  The service couldn't import the d.ts file for nothing.

Comment: @PostImpatica You're supposed to download the `element-resize-detector` package. The example above is a wrapper for that library. The `.d.ts` is not meant to be imported anywhere. It shows the api for said package.

Answer (score 7):

This angular 7 library does a pretty good job: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resize-event

```
<div (resized)="onResized($event)"></div>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// Import the resized event model
import { ResizedEvent } from 'angular-resize-event';

@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
  width: number;
  height: number;

  onResized(event: ResizedEvent) {
    this.width = event.newWidth;
    this.height = event.newHeight;
  }
}
```

Comment: this library caused an immense performance impact, just binding the resize event to a div caused the cpu usage to go up to 100%, so i have to assume they just keep checking the element width in a while(true) ... loop

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this [Angular2 directive](https://github.com/aminpaks/bound-sensor) to solve this.

You can install it by `npm install bound-sensor`.
The advantage of using this method is it tells you once the size of parent of component changes and it doesn't depend on window resize! Imagine you need to expand and refresh your content base on size of its parent, this solves it easily.

Answer (score 4):

My particular scenario was a little different, but I was able to solve it using `ResizeObserver` (without installing anything): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

```js
const htmlElem = document.getElementById("myDiv")

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(
  (entries) => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      if (entry.contentBoxSize) {
        // contentBoxSize is an array:
        console.log("entry.contentBoxSize: " + entry.contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize)
      } else {
        console.log("entry.contentRect: " + entry.contentRect.width)
      }
    }
  }
)
resizeObserver.observe(htmlElem)
```

I had two additional problems. This is not related to the question, but I want to explain them briefly:

- The DOM has to be rendered to use `getElementById()` or similar: add the code above in `ngAfterViewInit()`.
- CSS-Transitions causes a lot of calls: I implemented the callback function with `setTimeout` and a boolean `waitingForTransition` to call `setTimeout` only once. Other solution can be to remember the last time your function was called and call it only again if some time has passed.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy with: [@thalesrc/ng-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thalesrc/ng-utils) & [@thalesrc/resize-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thalesrc/resize-manager)

Install: `npm i -S @thalesrc/ng-utils @thalesrc/resize-manager`

```
import { ResizeModule } from '@thalesrc/ng-utils/resize';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ResizeModule
  ],
})
export class YourModule { }
```

then

```
<your-component thaResize (onResize)="postSizeChange($event)"></your-component>
```

or

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-component',
  template: ``
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private resizeService: ResizeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resizeService.observe(this.el.nativeElement).subscribe(({width, height}) => {
      console.log(width, height);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a directive.
[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-div-resize-demo?file=src/app/hook-resize.directive.ts)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative in order to be able to listen to a specific container that is resizing we can use 
`(window:resize)="onResize($event)"` in html
and in component in the method `onResize(event: UIEvent)` you can do whatever you want on resize.

Comment: this function is only triggered if the windows is resized, but not if the component itself is resized.

Comment: Other people have voted this Answer down, but for me, it's exactly what I needed.  Two lines of code, no third-party packages, and exactly the solution I needed to resize my component (redraw my charts within it) whenever the component size changed.   This isn't be the perfect solution (if the component height & width are absolutely sized, it pointlessly kicks off the event) but for my particular app, it worked perfectly.

Comment: The problem with this solution, again, is that it only fires if the window resizes.  But it doesn't fire if, say, a sidenav that pushes content when opened.  The window doesn't resize in that case, so this doesn't do that.

Comment: @JakeSmith That's good enough for many cases (incl. mine). There are trade-offs for every solution.