# Use element-resize-detector library in an Angular2 application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript2.0

I am trying to use the element-resize-detector library (https://github.com/wnr/element-resize-detector) in an Angular2 application.

From my limited JS module knowledge, the library appears to be in CommonJS format. After several attempts, I have created the following definition file (*.d.ts):

```
declare module ResizeDetector {
  function ResizeDetector(options: any): ResizeDetector.Erd;

  interface Erd {
    listenTo(element: any, resizeCallback: any): void;
    uninstall(element: any): void;
  }
}
export = ResizeDetector;
```

I then use the following import statement in my TypeScript code:

```
import * as ResizeDetector from 'element-resize-detector';
```

When running my app and using `console.log('ResizeDetector', ResizeDetector)`, the following output is logged:

```
ResizeDetector function (options) {
    options = options || {};

    //idHandler is currently not an option to the listenTo function, so it should not be added to globalOptions.
    var idHandler;

    if (options.…
```

This shows me that the library is successfully loaded and that it returns a function as expected.

My question is how can I now start using the library in TypeScript? When I attempt something like:

```
private static resizeDetector = ResizeDetector({ strategy: 'scroll' });
```

I get the following transpile error:

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### element-resize-detector.d.ts

```
declare function elementResizeDetectorMaker(options?: elementResizeDetectorMaker.ErdmOptions): elementResizeDetectorMaker.Erd;

declare namespace elementResizeDetectorMaker {
    interface ErdmOptions {
        strategy?: 'scroll' | 'object';
    }

    interface Erd {
        listenTo(element: HTMLElement, callback: (elem: HTMLElement) => void);
        removeListener(element: HTMLElement, callback: (elem: HTMLElement) => void);
        removeAllListeners(element: HTMLElement);
        uninstall(element: HTMLElement);
    }
}

export = elementResizeDetectorMaker;
```

#### Consumer

```
let resizeDetector = elementResizeDetectorMaker({ strategy: 'scroll'});
resizeDetector.listenTo(document.getElementById('abc'), (elem: HTMLElement) => {
    console.log(elem.offsetWidth, elem.offsetHeight);
})
```

Comment: I have to wrap the code in ```declare module 'element-resize-detector' { //your code here }``` in order for it to work.

Comment: Just putting it out here, have added a typings definition for the same: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/element-resize-detector

Answer (score 5):

Based on @stone-shi answer this is how I got it to work:

**Definition file:**

```
declare module 'element-resize-detector' {
  function elementResizeDetectorMaker(options?: elementResizeDetectorMaker.ErdmOptions): elementResizeDetectorMaker.Erd;

  namespace elementResizeDetectorMaker {
    interface ErdmOptions {
      strategy?: 'scroll' | 'object';
    }

    interface Erd {
      listenTo(element: HTMLElement, callback: (elem: HTMLElement) => void): void;
      removeListener(element: HTMLElement, callback: (elem: HTMLElement) => void): void;
      removeAllListeners(element: HTMLElement): void;
      uninstall(element: HTMLElement): void;
    }
  }

  export = elementResizeDetectorMaker;
}
```

**Ts file**

```
import * as elementResizeDetectorMaker from 'element-resize-detector';

    let _elementResizeDetector = elementResizeDetectorMaker({
      strategy: 'scroll'
    });
```